# Start a query on Activity A and handle result on Activity B

Tags: android

What I want to do is to start a query on Activity A (Let's say, using volley's stringRequest), and at the same time to start Activity B, and for the query's result to be handled on Activity B (Let's say, print it on a textview). How can this be achieved? Right now I only have everything handled on Activity A.

i.e. If i have some heavy operation on the onCreate of Activity B, I want to be able to at least have the API callback running in the background to save time.

I understand this is a race between "onResponse happening" and "Activity B is ready", the question being, how do I overcome this race?

Here's my code on Activity A -

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    String url = "https://myapp.mydomain.com/this/is/my/query";

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    String text = "Response is: "+ response;
                    Snackbar.make(mMainLayout, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                String text = error.getMessage();
                Snackbar.make(mMainLayout, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    });

    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you start the api call from ActivityB in the first place ? If the response is going to be handled in ActivityB, then let it call the api itself

Comment: @FarhadFaghihi That's not what I want, if i have some heavy operation on the onCreate of Activity B, I want to be able to at least have the API callback running in the background to save time.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to start your second activity inside onResponse

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
                String text = "Response is: "+ response;
                Snackbar.make(mMainLayout, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
I=new Intent(Main.this,second.class);
i.putExtra("stringname", response);
            }
```

Comment: That's not what I want, if i have some heavy operation on the onCreate of Activity B, I want to be able to at least have the API callback running in the background to save time.

Comment: You can also try sharedpreferences  in onResponse and then retrieve it in your second activity

Comment: Still won't help me - what if I try accessing the sharedpreferences from Activity B before the result is back?

Answer (score 0):

ActivityA

```
  @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    String text = "Response is: "+ response;
                    Snackbar.make(mMainLayout, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent i=new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class);
                i.putExtra("result",text);
                  startActivity(i);
                }
```

ActivityB

```
String result=getIntent().getExtras().getString("result");
//Handle response here
```

Comment: That's not what I want, if i have some heavy operation on the onCreate of Activity B, I want to be able to at least have the API callback running in the background to save time.

Answer (score 0):

Use Broadcasts Receivers [Example](http://hmkcode.com/android-sending-receiving-custom-broadcasts/)

When you get response from server then send broadcast and Register Receivers in Second Activity